# jQuery validationEngine: only validate fieldset

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-validation-engine

I'm building a 4-step form, where I only want to validate the currently visible fieldset. Each "step" has a submit-button, so I was hoping something along these lines:

```
$('#step-1-button').on('click', function(e){
    $('#step-1-fieldset').validationEngine('validate', {
    onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
        if(status){ goToNextStep() });
    }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly how the validationEngine plugin works - but a quick read of the docs suggests that you can call the 'validate' action on individual elements, and to validate only the visible fieldset you can use jquerys Filter method.

I would say something like

```
$('#step-1-button').on('click',function(e) {
       e.preventDefault(); 
       var inputs = $('fieldset').filter(':visible').find('input');
       $.each(inputs,function() { 
            $(this).validationEngine('validate');
       });
});
```

would work.

As you are filtering by the visible fieldset regardless of which button is clicked you can also attach the event to a generic selector - something like $('.step-button') - this will stop you from having to write a seperate event handler for each button in your 4 step form and will help keep your code DRY.

Comment: I'm gonna give this a go next week. I'll post whether or not it works out. It looks like it makes sense though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to validate only a portion of a form is to programmatically add and remove a class, such as "required".  Then run the validation on ".required" fields.  As you tab through the four steps of your form, strip out the required from all elements, and reapply only to the visible elements that need validation.  The nice thing about the jquery validation plugin is you don't need to re-run it anytime the DOM changes, it will automatically keep track of required and non-required fields as they are updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case is not bad to use **stepy form** with validation. it supports ajax also. 
Like Step 1,2,3.. + Validation
Here is what you want
[Demo](http://wbotelhos.com/stepy)